# Attachments not working after restore on different server

Tags: gitlab

I had my GitLab running on server a, I took the backup of GitLab through `rake` and restored on the different server b.

Although, I have changed the `external_url` wherever it was necessary, old attachments are yet showing invalid url.. http://gitlab.example.com/path_to_my_attachment

However, the new attachments are working fine and showing the valid path.

How can I fix the old attachment URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a current issue (reported in [issue 34073](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/34073)), being investigated in [issue 32789 "Links in projects don't update after external_url is changed"](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/32789)

> I noticed the following [Merge Request: !10597 (merged)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/10597)
>
> I think here we've found a valid reason where an admin would want to invalidate that cache and regenerate the contents of these fields.